# Does every surjective R-module homomorphism have a right inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

Can you tell me what's wrong in my proof ?

Proof:

Let f be a surjective R-module homomorphism from M to N.

For every $x\in N$ we let:

$A_{x}=\lbrace y \in M \mid f(y)=x \rbrace$, then $A_{x}$ is non-empty.

So $\prod A_{ x }$, $x\in M$ is non-empty, that mean there is an element $(y_{ x })_{ x\in M }$ (Choice' axiom)

Now, we define $f_{1}$ from N to M as follows:

for every $x \in M$ let $f_{1}(x)=y_{x}$.

Then $f\circ f_{1}=Id_{N}$

Comment: It's interesting because we can define $P$ to be a projective $R$-module provided any surjective $\alpha : M \to P$ has a right inverse $\beta : P \to M$ (i.e., $\alpha \beta = 1_P$). This suggests that if it's not projective, the result you want might not hold.

Comment: oh I have known my wrong !!!!!!!!!! $f_{1}$ which is establish above, maybe not R-modules homomorphism.

Comment: @Robert Carndona: That's right, I understand what your mean. Thanks!!!!

Comment: I tried to edit $x\in M$ after the definition of $A_x$ into $x\in N$ but it did not work, could someone do it?

Answer (score 4):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

You have used the Axiom of Choice to show that there exists a *function* $f_1 : N \to M$. You have not shown it is a *module homomorphism*, which may not be the case unless you add more hypothesis.